# Find the centralizer of the permutation in the alternating group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Suppose $\sigma = (1\hspace{3pt}4\hspace{3pt}3)(5\hspace{3pt}6\hspace{3pt}2\hspace{3pt}9)(7\hspace{3pt}8\hspace{3pt}10\hspace{3pt}11)$. How to find its centralizer in $A_{11}$?

Here is my attempt for $S_{11}$.

$\tau\sigma=\sigma\tau \iff \tau^{-1}\sigma\tau = \sigma$. Since $\sigma^{S_{11}}$ is a set of permutations of the same cycling type, we need to work only with them. It's clear that combinations of different powers of $\sigma$'s cycles are accepted, that is, $|St(\sigma)| \ge 3*4*4$. On the other hand, $|G(\sigma)| = \frac{11*10*9}{3}*\frac{\frac{8*7*6*5}{4}*\frac{4*3*2*1}{4}}{2}$, and $|St(\sigma)| = \frac{|S_{11}|}{|G(\sigma)|} = 3*4*4*2$. How to find others? (Or what's wrong with counting?). And what to do in the case of $A_{11}$? Just divide by $2$?

Comment: The two 4-cycles can be swapped by $\tau$ (e.g. $\tau=(3\ 7)(6\ 8)(2\ 10)(9\ 11)$), which gives you your factor of $2$. Now that you know all the possibilities for $\tau$ in $S_{11}$, just pick out the ones with even parity.

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.